# Keep a text field focused despite clicking elsewhere

Tags: javascript, html, focus

I want to keep the text field focused, despite clicking on the red div. I try different methods, why nothing works?

```js
function stopEvent(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   e.preventDefault();
   return false;    
}
function setFocus(e) {
   document.getElementById("textField").focus();
   stopEvent(e);
}
document.getElementById("textField").focus();
```

```html
<div onmouseover="setFocus(event);" onfocus="this.blur();">
  <div style="background-color:red; height:100px;" onclick="stopEvent(event)" onfocus="this.blur();">Click area</div>
  <div><input id="textField" type="text" value="focused" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you add an ID to an element than you can refer to it by `window.textField`. Still you should avoid setting IDs on elements in projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used stopEvent instead of setFocus on your click area div. Also you didn't return false in the setFocus so the return false in stopEvent was useless.

```js
function stopEvent(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   e.preventDefault();
   return false;    
}
function setFocus(e) {
   document.getElementById("textField").focus();
   return stopEvent(e);
}
document.getElementById("textField").focus();
```

```html
<div onmouseover="setFocus(event);" onfocus="this.blur();">
  <div style="background-color:red; height:100px;" onclick="setFocus(event)" onfocus="this.blur();">Click area</div>
  <div><input id="textField" type="text" value="focused" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How to prevent focus change also on wheel click?

Answer (score 2):

Just add `document.getElementById("textField").addEventListener('blur',() => document.getElementById("textField").focus())` if you want it to be always focused.

```js
document.getElementById("textField").focus();
document.getElementById("textField").addEventListener('blur',() => 
document.getElementById("textField").focus())
```

```html
<div>
  <div style="background-color:red; height:100px;">Click area</div>
  <div><input id="textField" type="text" value="focused" /></div>
</div>
```

If you want to refocus when red div is clicked than just add 'click' event listener to the redDiv.

```js
window.textField.focus();
window.redBox.addEventListener('click',() => window.textField.focus())
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="redBox" style="background-color:red; height:100px;">Click area</div>
  <div><input id="textField" type="text" value="focused" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this trick

```js
const field = document.getElementById("textField");

field.addEventListener("blur", function( event ) {
  setTimeout(function () {
      field.focus();
    }, 100);   
}, true);
```

```html
<div style="background-color:red; height:100px;">Click area</div>
<div><input id="textField" type="text" value="focused" /></div>
```